# Different animation simultaneous in TableLayout and images views childs

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a RelativeLayout with 4 ImeButtons inside.
I want a animation for alpha fade in to Relative layout and at same time, ImageViews are showing from bottom to screen to them position.

Is this possible?

Now being applied the same animation (Translation) to all views , I want you dare ImageButtons with translation animate and TableLayout appears with alpha animation

```
public class Panel extends TableLayout {

    private Animation showAnimation;
    private ImageButton bt;
    private ImageButton bt2;
    private ImageButton bt3;
    private ImageButton bt4;

    public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflateViewWith(context);
        loadAnimationResource();
        setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void mapGui() {
        //findviewsbyid
    }

    public void setNewViewAndAnimate(int newVisibility) {
        if (newVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            startAnimation(showAnimation);
            animateIcons();
        } else {
            setVisibility(newVisibility);
        }
    }

    private void animateIcons() {
        animateIcon(bt);
        animateIcon(bt1);
        animateIcon(bt2);
        animateIcon(bt3);
    }

private void loadAnimationResource() {
    showAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.view_changes_alpha_show);
}
    private void animateIcon(View view) {
        Animation translateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.panel_icons_show);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
    }

    private void inflateViewWith(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.pane, this, true);
    }
}
```

panel_icons_show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:duration="600"
           android:fillAfter="true"
           android:fromXDelta="100%p"
           android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
           android:toXDelta="0"
           android:toYDelta="0"/>
```

And other view contains this customview, inflate by tag and i set current visibility from public method and animate icons..But this applies transform animation to all the view and to the icons..

Comment: please, provide your code for further support

Comment: Done, sorry i forgot it.

Comment: you forgot the Panel_icons_Show.XML which provides the core function of your issue.. ;P

Comment: This is not important, the translation movement its correct (I have invented values), its same effect with translation, scale or whatever..But i edit my question with it.

Comment: Your sentence: Actually i set the animations but its applied the same animation to all the views at same time.. isn't that exactly what you want or do you mean with all even the RelativeLayout? Do they animate right now the correct way? i don't clearly understand how they act right now..or do they just fade in or do they just move from the bottom to specified Position?

Comment: it's not really clear what you mean.. please be exact. First of all, you got 4 ImagesButtons and not ImageViews These are different...

Comment: Sorry my english its not very good, i edited my question.

I want alpha animation to TableLayout and translator animation to each ImageButton, but actually Translate animations are appling to all views at same time.

Answer (score 0):

What i can see and what i know from our talk..

```
public void setNewViewAndAnimate(int newVisibility) {
    if (newVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        startAnimation(showAnimation);
        animateIcons();
    } else {
        setVisibility(newVisibility);
    }
}
```

That you don't set which view should fade in, you only call

```
startAnimation(showAnimation);
```

and in Show Animation you only load the Animation, but you don't declare which View should get the Animation... maybe that's the Point. Just a guess.

Give me update

Comment: In this context this is same as this.startAnimation(showAnimation)...Apply animation to this (TableLayout)

Comment: @colymore yeah this was my second guess, but i wasn't sure